# how to share a public key

Tags: java, public-key

My question is not about how to create a public key in java, but how do I send it to another client.

I have a server and two clients communicating with each other, when a client tries to send a message, the program **encrypts** it using the clients **private key**, then, it sends the **encrypted byte array** throw the stream with the other clients **public key**, this is my point, how do they know each other?

Is there a way to send the public key to a specific client?

Comment: Nice question. There's only one problem: a proper answer fills entire books, not the simple answer-format here. A good point to start is always [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_exchange). And this sounds a lot like roll-your-own cryptography. So an advice in advance: **NEVER** use any cryptographic protocol you developed on your own in anything but experimental setups that are never used in any "serious" way. There are plenty of protocols out there that do exactly what you want.

Comment: Thank you Paul for your quick answer, I'll study and if I find a good solution will post is here.